# how to select rows of a matrix on the basis of occurrence of elements in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, row, matrix-indexing

i have a [sentence cross words] matrix as follows.

```
x = [ 0 1 1 0 1
      1 1 1 0 0
      0 0 1 1 0
      1 1 0 1 1
      0 0 0 0 0 ];
```

`0` shows a word is present in respective sentence and `1` shows a word is absent in the respective sentence, i have done some processing and selected `word number 2,3 and 5` from the columns.
I want to select those sentences (rows) on the basis of `word 2,3 and 5` in which any two or more than two words appear, single appearance of word in a sentence should not be considered

For example  from above matrix sentence number 1, 2 and 4 should be selected because `word 2,3 and 5` occurs in them and sentence `number 3 and 5` should not be considered because in sentence `3` only word 3 appears alone without `2 and 5`. if there was `2` or `5` present in sentence `3` it should be selected because more than two words occured together in a senence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach to select those valid rows from `x` -

```
x_valid = x(sum(x(:,[2 3 5]),2)>=2,:)
```

Instead, if you are interested in knowing just the valid indices -

```
idx = find(sum(x(:,[2 3 5]),2)>=2)
```

Sample run -

```
x =
     0     1     1     0     1
     1     1     1     0     0
     0     0     1     1     0
     1     1     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0
x_valid =
     0     1     1     0     1
     1     1     1     0     0
     1     1     0     1     1
idx =
     1
     2
     4
```